# Unable to execute function of module

Tags: node.js

Kinda new to Node, though I've worked with JS for the past few years.

So I'm trying to execute a function in a module, though Node keeps returning `TypeError: module.hello is not a function`, despite the fact that `typeof module.hello` returns `function`.

Code:

**main.js**

```js
const module = require(bot.dir + "/server.js");
console.log(module.isThisHere);
console.log(module);
module.hello();
```

... /**server.js** (module)

```js
. . .
module.exports = {
  "isThisHere": "Yes",
  hello () {
    console.log("Hello!");
  },
  execute (bot) {
     . . .
  }
}
```

Console:

```js
"Yes"
{
  isThisHere: 'Yes',
  hello: [Function: hello],
  execute: [Function: execute]
}
TypeError: module.hello is not a function
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `module` is the global parameter of node.js, name it `fooBar`

Comment: Tried, still receiving the same error.